# how to insert php var in code

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have got this working code using `wordpress` and [`advanced custom fields`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com):

```
$include = get_pages('include=1575');
$title = apply_filters('the_title',$include[0]->post_title);
$content = apply_filters('the_content',$include[0]->post_content);
```

I want to create a `var` replacing the `post_id` in `include=1575`. I get this var using:

```
$site_id = the_field('id_grundgedanke'); // output exp: 1575
```

How I can I combine these? I have tried the following:

```
 $site_id = the_field('id_grundgedanke');
 $include = get_pages('include=' . $site_id);
 $title = apply_filters('the_title',$include[0]->post_title);
 $content = apply_filters('the_content',$include[0]->post_content);
```

Which does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [get_field()](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) instead of [the_field()](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/).

> **get_field()** - Returns the value of the specified field.
>
> **the_field()** - Displays the value of the specified field. This function
>   is the same as `echo get_field($field_name)`;

Corrected code:

```
 $site_id = get_field('id_grundgedanke'); // use get_field
 $include = get_pages("include=" . $site_id);
 $title = apply_filters('the_title',$include[0]->post_title);
 $content = apply_filters('the_content',$include[0]->post_content);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understand this :P

Comment: there is one mistake, "include=$site_id" does not work. I have suggested the necessary edit!

Comment: @MarianRick: It should work. don't know the reason.  anyway thanks for your edit. :-)

Comment: Receiving the following in debug modus: `Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /wp-content/themes/aupair2000/page_cover-site.php on line 73

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /wp-content/themes/aupair2000/page_cover-site.php on line 73

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /wp-content/themes/aupair2000/page_cover-site.php on line 74

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /wp-content/themes/aupair2000/page_cover-site.php on line 74`

Comment: @MarianRick: You should print $include and check what data you are receiving. Write **echo '<pre>'; print_r($include)**;